# Grunt - get server with livereload up and running

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I've been staring at my grunt config for a couple of hours now and can't seem to get things up and running.

My files are building where I'm expecting them (basically just in place where they are, apart from handlebars) but I'm really struggling with getting an autorefreshing server up and running. Can't quite get it up and running.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be a massive help!

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            files: {
                'assets/css/style.css' : 'assets/css/*.scss'
            }       
        },
        assemble: {
            options: {
                flatten: true,
                assets: 'assets',
                layout: 'templates/layouts/main.hbs'
            },
            pages: {
                src: ['templates/*.hbs'],
                dest: '.'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            all: {
                files: '**/*.hbs',
                tasks: ['assemble'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: 'assets/css/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
            scripts: {
                files: 'assets/js/*.js',
            },
            livereload: {
                options : { livereload: true },
                files: ['/']
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                livereload: 35729,
                hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                keepalive: true,
                open: true
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch','connect']);
}
```

Comment: Well did you download LiveReload or install the chrome extension?

Comment: Installed the chrome extension. I've had it working with other grunt builds that I didn't set up, but this is the first grunt archive I've written from scratch myself.

Comment: [I've got a repo that uses livereload](https://github.com/andywillis/EVL) - you're welcome to take a look at it. It uses `load-grunt-config` to split up the config file into smaller pieces (in the grunt folder); the files you should be looking at are `Gruntfile.js`, `grunt/connect.js`, and `grunt/watch.js`. You also need the node module `connect-livereload` as well as `grunt-config-connect`. Took me ages to figure out how to put it all together so I understand your pain.

Comment: I'll take a look at that thank you. I've been looking through so many repos for hints, I think I'm blind to it now. It's such an open-ended tool and there are so many way to skin the grunt cat, it's hard to find a snippet that perfectly fits with the setup I'm using!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I managed to get working with the help of a friend - was using some out of date modules. Hope it's of use to someone!

> module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        all: {
            files: {
                'assets/css/style.css' : 'assets/css/main.scss'
            }   
        }
    },
    assemble: {
        options: {
            flatten: true,
            assets: 'assets',
            layout: 'templates/layouts/main.hbs'
        },
        pages: {
            src: ['templates/*.hbs'],
            dest: '.'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        assemble: {
            files: 'templates/**/*.hbs',
            tasks: ['assemble']
        },
        sass: {
            files: 'assets/css/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass']
        },
        css: {
            files:['assets/css/*.css']
        },
        scripts: {
            files: 'assets/js/*.js',
        },
        livereload: {
            options : { livereload: true },
            files: ['*.html','assets/css/*.css','assets/js/*.js']
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9001,
            livereload: true,
            hostname: '0.0.0.0'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: ['.']
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

grunt.registerTask('default',['connect','watch']);
```

}